# Live Channel Streaming on web Page

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am working on a project in which I want to play different types of news channels live on my website

Here is my code in which I am trying to play the channels

```
<div class="video_box">
    <iframe id="example_video_1" 
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
            controls preload="none" 
            width="562" 
            height="370" 
            poster="images/movie_clip.png" 
            data-setup="{}"
            src="link to the live streaming channel">
    </iframe>                    
</div>
```

Now the problem is when I put the src of the channel in my iframe src tag it gives error and channel does not play.

I have tried to play the channel on the same player as it is playing on the channel website but still didnt get the result.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy the embedded source code from the channel iframe link given on the channel websites. Different website will just also provide the iframe link for the news channel to be displayed on your site. Just copy that iframe code and paste it on your website install the player on your site page and run the page the channel will start streaming on your page.

Answer (score 0):

first of all are you copying the embedded source code or just the channel iframe link..???
there is difference between two for eg: to run youtube vedio directly on your side you need to copy embedded source code which is available on youtube share button and then click embedded and u will get iframe embedded source code. similar goes for news channels [check this link might help you](http://www.ehow.com/how_12187303_embed-tv-channel-mysite.html)